# How do I create a rule that disallows the Assigned To from changing the state to Closed in Azure Boards work items?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I want the user who is changing the state to Closed to not be the same user who the work item is assigned to.

It can't be a group based rule, because user A can review user B's work and vice versa.

**Why? (Background)**

I want to have an audit trail of who did the work (I'm thinking "Assigned To") and who reviewed it against our Definition of Done (I'm thinking "Closed By"), and that can't be the same person (4 eyes principle).
Also, I like Closed By because it is automatically set when the state is changed to Closed, and the system prevents any user from changing it even if it is added to the layout.

I considered adding a "Meets DoD" boolean field and then capturing who checked it in a "DoD Reviewed By" field, but I could not figure out how to prevent the user from changing the "DoD Reviewed By" field. So, it appears that the behavior of the built-in field "Closed By" cannot be replicated on a custom field.

I am open to other creative solutions to accomplish this goal if the primary ask is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid of Azure devops doesnot have the feature to prevent the Assigned to from changing the state to Closed.

You probably need to create a group to include these users who are allowed to close the work items.

And then define a rule to Restrict a transition based on State and user or group membership. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops#workflow-rules) for more information.

So that these users who are not in the group are not allowed to change the state to closed.

[image]

Comment: I explained in my post why this wouldn't work: "because user A can review user B's work and vice versa."

Comment: @successhawk I am afraid current available work item rules cannot achieve this. You can submit a feature request [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21).

Comment: I marked this as accepted for the first paragraph, it appears to be not possible.